# Why mkfs can write the SSD at a speed of 10GB/s

Tags: ext4, ssd, mkfs

I have an intel SSD 480GB. It's peak write speed is about 300MB/s under various benchmark programs (including dd and programs written by myself). However, when I execute `mkfs.ext4` with the option `-E lazy_itable_init=0` on it, the iostat shows that it is performing 8GB/s to 10GB/s write speed. How can this happen?

For questions to be simple, how can I write a program that performs write operations on the SSD to make the iostat report 10GB/s? While `mkfs.ext4` can achieve, I think a program we write purposely should also be able to achieve.

Comment: I don't know the fetails, but pretty sure ithis 10 GB/s is not the transfer speed (even SATA-3.2 peaks at around 2 GB/s), but the rate at which the flash blocks of the SSD are erased.

Comment: That makes sense. But if the bus limits the speed to 2GB/s, iostat can not report more higher results even the underlying SSD can erase (I think erase is another form of write) at the rate of 10GB/s, right? Or, how can we imitate mkfs to make the iostat report that rate? These are just my doubts and I think you have given a great clue. Thank you!

Comment: For a HDD, erasing is a form of writing, yes. But for a flash-based device the process is not symmetrical. You can set individual bits in one direction, but it's a different physical principal to reset then, which is done for whole blocks of memory only. I'm not familiar with the protocol used for the transfer, but obviously you don't transfer gigabytes of zeroes. Maybe the mkfs-sources can reveal how to reproduce this.

Comment: I agree with you that it's a business of studying the mkfs-source.